# How to partially extract a JSON string to get a specific object by name

Tags: c#, json, unit-testing, deserialization, mstest

I have the following json string:

```
 "{"\"itemList\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Item 1 Name\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Item 2 Name\"}],"listInfo":{"info1":1,"info2":"bla"}}"
```

How can I extract specific objects into a string?  For example, I want to get a new string out of it that looks like this:

`[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Item 1 Name\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Item 2 Name\"}]`

and another string that looks like this:

`{"info1":1,"info2":"bla"}`.

The first string represents the `itemList` object (which holds an array) and the second string represents the `listInfo` object.

My objective is to compare these strings to other other objects that I plan to serialize for unit testing.

Comment: No it was not the same thing. This question is the result of the answer I received from another post.  I created a new post because it is my understanding that a post must be for a specific question. If that is the cause for downvoting then I don't see the sense in that. Should I change my question in the other post?

Comment: Ok. I really don't understand why someone would downvote for no reason.  Is this not a valid question? I'm happy to delete it if it isn't, but I would like to know why.

Comment: You could probably improve this question by posting the unescaped and formatted version of your json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a DTO for your JSON string:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public List<ItemList> itemList = new List<ItemList>();
    public ListInfo listInfo = new ListInfo();
}

class ItemList
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

class ListInfo
{
    public string info1 { get; set; }
    public string info2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then: (after I fixed the JSON string format)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

string jsonString = "{\"itemList\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Item 1 Name\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Item 2 Name\"}],\"listInfo\":{\"info1\":1,\"info2\":\"bla\"}}";

BaseClass toCompare = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseClass>(jsonString);
string itemList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toCompare.itemList);
string listInfo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toCompare.listInfo);
```